# multiple database connection (undesired)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am trying to get to grips with OOP a little better.

i am using this __construct method wthin all my class files
This is functioning fine, and as expected

```
private $conn; // database connection

// make database connection if not exist!
function __construct() {
    // autoload class files
    require_once('class/autoloader.php'); 
    spl_autoload_register('myAutoloader');

    // open db connection so it is available to all files
    $db = new dbconn();
    $this->conn = $db->get_connection();        
}
```

However, i have multiple class files that all reference eachother, so as the database connection is being loaded into all class files does this mean i am opening too many connections.
AND do i need to close each instance of the connection? (if so this is tricky as i dont always know what class files may have been initiated).

I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: put the database connection in a config file. put *anything* that's required in all your scripts in a config file. the way you're doing it means if the password changes you have to update *all* of those files. yuck!

Comment: A possible solution would be to use dependancy injection: create one global db connection and pass that as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: thanks Tim. the passwords are in a single config file. if i add the database connection to a config file too, it will not be available to my classes unless i inject it into all functions that require it.

Comment: ahhh, thanks Jeroen, that would make sense and be neater :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above does not give enough context to answer if anything is actually wrong.

Some things to keep in mind.

the __construct function will get called anytime you create a new instance of this class. If you only create one instance of this class and share the instance with any of the other classes you are using, you will be fine.

```
// Use DI to pass in the database connection.
function __construct($dbConn) {
    $this->conn = $dbConn;        
}
```

Comment: thanks Jmaloney. Thanks. the code above does work and in context it does not technically error, but as you say i am loading multiple instances and have the same __construct in all class files too, so i will be opening multiple connections. i am wondering if this is wrong. However as Jeroen said above, i think i should maybe just pass the connection into the __construct, this way i only have 1 connection across the whole app

Comment: @Ford dependency injection would be a great way to go.

Comment: outside of the class, is $dbConn = NULL; enough to close the connection? and within any class i injected it into?

Answer (score 0):

@Ford another thing you could do is create a function that will connect to the database when it is called. This way you do not have your database connection active even when you are not using it. It would allow your scripts to run a little bit faster because you will be calling a resource only when you  need it.

You can also have a close connection function that you will call whenever you are done executing your queries and no longer in need of your DB connection.